# jQuery dialog is not opening form second time and is instead going to the login page

Tags: jquery, dialog

I am using the jQuery dialog library to display a dialog box. The dialog box initially opens perfectly. However, from the second time onwards, the dialog opens and immediately redirects to my login page. I need it to perform the given actions before moving to the login page.

**javascript:**

```
function exportOptionDialog(){ 
    $("#exportOptionDialog").dialog({      
        dialogClass : "flora",
        resizable: false,
        width : "500px",       
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: sampleUrl,
        cache: false,   
        success: function(result) {   
            $('#exportOptionDialog').html(result);              
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: it may not be JS error, but PHP or other server side language You are using. Check the params that are going to the server

Comment: Even it is not showing any error in browser console.

Comment: Check REQUEST params! :)